# How to vertically center divs in my navbar

Tags: html, css

My question is simple, how I'm able to vertically center divs in my navbar so they will be always in the center no matter what height of the navbar i set. I have already tried `vertical-align: middle;` but that didn't work for me.

**HTML:**

```html
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="homeButton"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></button>
            <button class="schoolButton"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i>mySchool</button>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="#">Programování</a>
            <a href="#">Anglický jazyk</a>
            <a href="#">Psychologie</a>
            <a href="#">Zdraví a psychohygiena</a>
            <a href="#">Matematika</a>
            <a href="#">Logické úlohy</a>
            <a href="#">Programy</a>
            <a href="#">Ostatní</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.navbar {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
}

.buttons {
  float: left;
}

.links {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using float for this is a deprecated solution, better to do it like this:

```
.navbar {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot. I just used align-items: space-between; and then marge my divs to make one on the left and the other one on the right.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to place the items halfway down a div. e.g.

```
.verticalCenter {
    top: 50%;
}
```

then just add it to the buttons div.

```
    <div class="buttons verticalCenter"> <!-- added here -->
        <button class="homeButton"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></button>
        <button class="schoolButton"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i>mySchool</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use flexbox.

```css
.navbar {
  /*rest of your code*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}
```